# Why the value in the List is overwirting with new values?

Tags: android, list, hashmap

I'm having a list where filling the values to list through looping as below.

```
List<String> labelGroupDataValue = null;

    if (labelGroupData.size() != 0) {
                            for (HashMap<String, List<String>> LabelMap : labelGroupData) {
                                for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> labelGroupDataEntry : LabelMap.entrySet()) {
                                    if (labelGroupDataEntry.getKey() != null) {
                                        String keyvalue = labelGroupDataEntry.getKey();
                                        if (keyvalue.contains(key)) {
                                            labelGroupDataValue = labelGroupDataEntry.getValue();
                                            CheckIsCustomizings(labelGroupDataValue);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

The problem i'm facing is labelGroupDataValue contains the data of only last looping.

Where i'm doing wrong, could you please help me in this regard.

Code for IsCustomizings:

private void CheckIsCustomizings(List> value) {
        // Looping through the List to check whether Customizings syncGroup is present or not
        for (int j = 0; j < value.size(); j++) {

```
        if (value.get(j).equals("SALESDOCS")) {
            value.set(j, "SALES_DOCUMENTS");
        }

        if (value.get(j).equalsIgnoreCase("TRADEASSETS")) {
            value.set(j, "TRADE_ASSETS");
        }

        if (value.get(j).equalsIgnoreCase("PROMOTIONSCAMPAIGNS")) {
            value.set(j, "PROMOTIONS_CAMPAIGNS");
        }

        String checkName = "CUSTOMIZINGS";
        if (value.get(j).toLowerCase().contains(checkName.toLowerCase())) {
            IsCustomizingPresent = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    // If Customizings syncGroup is not present, add the same to List for displaying to the user
    if (!IsCustomizingPresent) {
        value.add("CUSTOMIZING");
    }
}
```

Comment: post code of CheckIsCustomizings as well

Comment: @Anjali, I have added the code.

Comment: `labelGroupDataValue = labelGroupDataEntry.getValue();` You initialize the variable every time, thus only the last key found will be considered, all the work you do before that is discarded

Comment: @Ilario, could you let me know on how to proceed further?

Comment: @coders posted an answer with correct initialization of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to correctly add to an existing list:

```
List<String> labelGroupDataValue = new ArrayList<>();

if (labelGroupData.size() != 0) {

   ... //omissis

   labelGroupDataValue.addAll(labelGroupDataEntry.getValue());
   CheckIsCustomizings(labelGroupDataValue);

   ...
}
```

The correctness of the rest of the code is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize "labelGroupDataValue" inside the forloop,
what's happening now is there is only single memory is allocated to the list which get overwritten everytime in the loop, hence only the last value stays.

try the below code if it helps

```
List<String> labelGroupDataValue = null;

if (labelGroupData.size() != 0) {
                        for (HashMap<String, List<String>> LabelMap : labelGroupData) {
                            for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> labelGroupDataEntry : LabelMap.entrySet()) {
                                if (labelGroupDataEntry.getKey() != null) {
                                    String keyvalue = labelGroupDataEntry.getKey();
                                    labelGroupDataValue = new ArrayList<>();
                                    if (keyvalue.contains(key)) {
                                        labelGroupDataValue = labelGroupDataEntry.getValue();
                                        CheckIsCustomizings(labelGroupDataValue);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```